# How to draw a static length line at random y values

Tags: c#, graphics, line, draw, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to create a mini game where you must use a "turret" to shoot at a target. Currently I'm stuck on my target line. My aim is to get it to spawn at a set X value but for it to spawn at a random Y value everytime I press the redraw button. However I'm having trouble with my code. Instead of the line always being the same length and spawning at random Y values, it seems to be spawning at random lengths and at random Y values. If anyone could help me figure out where I have gone wrong that would be perfect.

The relevant variables are `xTarget`, `yTarget` (the first y value of the line) `yTargetEnd` (the second y value of the line) `targetLine` (the static length of the line) and the `DrawLine()` method call for `targetLine`.

In my head the way I have it set up makes sense but it doesn't seem to be doing what I expect. I try to set `yTarget` to a random number and then set `yTargetEnd` to `yTarget + targetLine`, so it should always be 50 in length, but that doesn't seem to work at all?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Random rnd = new Random { };
    double xEnd = 0;
    double yEnd = 0;
    double xOrigin = 30;
    double yOrigin = 450;
    double xFire;
    double yFire;
    double xTarget = 500;
    double yTarget;
    double yTargetEnd;
    double xHor = 30;
    double yHor = 350;
    double xVert = 130;
    double yVert = 450;
    double fireLine = 750;
    double lineLength = 50;
    double targetLine = 50;

    public Form1()
    {
        xEnd = xOrigin + lineLength;
        yEnd = yOrigin;
        xFire = xOrigin + fireLine;
        yFire = yOrigin;

        InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    private void LineDrawEvent(object sender, PaintEventArgs paint)
    {
        Graphics drawSurface = paint.Graphics;
        Pen turretLine = new Pen(Color.Blue);
        Pen graphHorizontal = new Pen(Color.Red);
        Pen graphVertical = new Pen(Color.Red);
        Pen firedLine = new Pen(Color.Blue);
        Pen targetLine = new Pen(Color.Black);
        float[] dashValues = { 5, 2 };
        firedLine.DashPattern = dashValues;

        drawSurface.DrawLine(graphVertical, (int)xOrigin, (int)yOrigin, (int)xHor, (int)yHor);
        drawSurface.DrawLine(graphHorizontal, (int)xOrigin, (int)yOrigin, (int)xVert, (int)yVert);
        drawSurface.DrawLine(firedLine, (int)xOrigin, (int)yOrigin, (int)xFire, (int)yFire);
        drawSurface.DrawLine(targetLine, (int)xTarget, (int)yTarget, (int)xTarget, (int)yTargetEnd);

        double angleInRadians = ConvertDegsToRads((double)trckBarAngle.Value);
        xEnd = xOrigin + lineLength * Math.Cos(angleInRadians / 2.0);
        yEnd = yOrigin - lineLength * Math.Sin(angleInRadians / 2.0);

        drawSurface.DrawLine(turretLine, (int)xOrigin, (int)yOrigin, (int)xEnd, (int)yEnd);
        this.Refresh();
    }

    private void trckBarAngle_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblAngle.Text = "Angle is:" + Convert.ToString((double)trckBarAngle.Value / 2.0);  
    }

    private double ConvertDegsToRads(double degrees)
    {
        return degrees * (Math.PI / 180.0);
    }

    private void btnFire_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double angleInDegrees = trckBarAngle.Value;

        double angleInRadians = ConvertDegsToRads(angleInDegrees);
        xFire = xOrigin + fireLine * Math.Cos(angleInRadians / 2.0);
        yFire = yOrigin - fireLine * Math.Sin(angleInRadians / 2.0);
        this.Refresh();
    }

    private void btnRedraw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        yTargetEnd = yTarget - targetLine;
        yTarget = rnd.Next(100, 500);
    }
}
```

Designer-generated code:

```
partial class Form1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.lblAngle = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.trckBarAngle = new System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar();
        this.btnFire = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.btnRedraw = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.trckBarAngle)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // lblAngle
        // 
        this.lblAngle.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblAngle.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 13);
        this.lblAngle.Name = "lblAngle";
        this.lblAngle.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(46, 17);
        this.lblAngle.TabIndex = 0;
        this.lblAngle.Text = "label1";
        // 
        // trckBarAngle
        // 
        this.trckBarAngle.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.trckBarAngle.LargeChange = 10;
        this.trckBarAngle.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(732, 42);
        this.trckBarAngle.Maximum = 360;
        this.trckBarAngle.Minimum = -360;
        this.trckBarAngle.Name = "trckBarAngle";
        this.trckBarAngle.Orientation = System.Windows.Forms.Orientation.Vertical;
        this.trckBarAngle.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(56, 495);
        this.trckBarAngle.TabIndex = 1;
        this.trckBarAngle.Scroll += new System.EventHandler(this.trckBarAngle_Scroll);
        // 
        // btnFire
        // 
        this.btnFire.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(632, 13);
        this.btnFire.Name = "btnFire";
        this.btnFire.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.btnFire.TabIndex = 2;
        this.btnFire.Text = "Fire";
        this.btnFire.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.btnFire.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnFire_Click);
        // 
        // btnRedraw
        // 
        this.btnRedraw.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(713, 13);
        this.btnRedraw.Name = "btnRedraw";
        this.btnRedraw.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.btnRedraw.TabIndex = 2;
        this.btnRedraw.Text = "Redraw";
        this.btnRedraw.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.btnRedraw.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnRedraw_Click);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 549);
        this.Controls.Add(this.btnRedraw);
        this.Controls.Add(this.btnFire);
        this.Controls.Add(this.trckBarAngle);
        this.Controls.Add(this.lblAngle);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.LineDrawEvent);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.trckBarAngle)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblAngle;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar trckBarAngle;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnFire;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnRedraw;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic issue comes down to the code simply not matching what you intended. You wrote:

> I try to set `yTarget` to a random number and then set `yTargetEnd` to `yTarget + targetLine`

But that's not actually what the code does. Your code does those two things in the opposite order. So the `yTargetEnd` value is always based on the *previous* target location, not the newly selected one.

Your code should look like this instead:

```
private void btnRedraw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    yTarget = rnd.Next(100, 500);
    yTargetEnd = yTarget - targetLine;
}
```

I.e. write the code so that it matches your specification. :)

Having answered that, there are some other important issues to address in your code:

- First and foremost, you are updating the screen in completely the wrong way. You should not call `Refresh()`, `Update()`, or `Invalidate()` from a `Paint` event handler. Instead, you should have separate logic somewhere, e.g. based on a timer, background thread, etc. that handles control of the state of the data (i.e. your game world), and which invalidates the relevant window or control(s) if and when the data changes in a way that would require them to be redrawn.
- Also, you should use the stock `Pen` objects when possible, and when not possible, either dispose of your custom `Pen` object or store it somewhere for reuse.

For example:

```
private static readonly Pen _firedLine =
    new Pen(Color.Blue) { DashPattern = new [] { 5f, 2f } };

private void LineDrawEvent(object sender, PaintEventArgs paint)
{
    Graphics drawSurface = paint.Graphics;
    Pen turretLine = Pens.Blue;
    Pen graphHorizontal = Pens.Red;
    Pen graphVertical = Pens.Red;
    Pen targetLine = Pens.Black;

    drawSurface.DrawLine(graphVertical, (int)xOrigin, (int)yOrigin, (int)xHor, (int)yHor);
    drawSurface.DrawLine(graphHorizontal, (int)xOrigin, (int)yOrigin, (int)xVert, (int)yVert);
    drawSurface.DrawLine(_firedLine, (int)xOrigin, (int)yOrigin, (int)xFire, (int)yFire);
    drawSurface.DrawLine(targetLine, (int)xTarget, (int)yTarget, (int)xTarget, (int)yTargetEnd);

    double angleInRadians = ConvertDegsToRads((double)trckBarAngle.Value);
    xEnd = xOrigin + lineLength * Math.Cos(angleInRadians / 2.0);
    yEnd = yOrigin - lineLength * Math.Sin(angleInRadians / 2.0);

    drawSurface.DrawLine(turretLine, (int)xOrigin, (int)yOrigin, (int)xEnd, (int)yEnd);
}
```